# Сместить позицию чтения до нужного тега

Tags: html, c++, парсер

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="1"/>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="main.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

код на C++

```
xmlNode *root = NULL;
htmlDocPtr doc;
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

xmlNode * look_for_start_point(xmlNode *nodenode){
    xmlNode *innernode;
    if (nodenode == NULL){ // проверяем на NULL входные данные
       return 0;
    }

    for (innernode=nodenode;innernode; innernode=innernode->next) // пока не кончатся теги
        if (innernode->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE && xmlStrcmp(innernode->name, (const xmlChar *)"div") == 0){
            //ищем тег div и если нашли, то возвращаем указатель
            return innernode;
        } else { //если нет - проверяем следующий тег
            look_for_start_point(innernode->children);
        }          
    }

}

root = look_for_start_point(root);
printf("Current node is %s\n", root->name);
```

Как найти div и поставить текущий указатель на него?

Comment: Библиотека libxml2

Comment: Ошибка(1) : xmlStrcmp(nodenode->name, (const xmlChar *)"div") ==0 (как и стандартный strcmp, если строки совпадают, то функция возвращает 0, т.е. false). Ошибка(2) : результат возвращаемый из рекурсивного вызова look_for_start_point ты вообще не анализируешь ....

Comment: Переделал, но валится теперь вообще.

Comment: (3) innernode->children - может быть равен NULL (если нет детей). А в начале функции аргумент не проверяется на null.  (4) результат возвращаемый look_for_start_point все еще не проверяется.

Comment: Хм.. исправил, но опять не работает.

Comment: Теперь, в точке вызова  look_for_start_point ты уже вышел из цикла. Т.е. innernode == NULL, а ты делаешь innernode->children ...